# What does this mean? "...along an otherwise two-way main road"

Tags: meaning

Read it on Today on Bing, here's the whole paragraph:

> The Pont Fawr is itself the stuff of history: Built in the 1630s, it's often called the 'Inigo Jones bridge' after the pioneering early modern architect who, legend has it, designed the triple-arch span that today carries motor traffic. **A one-way bottleneck along an otherwise two-way main road,** the bridge's humped shape tends to obscure oncoming cars, earning it yet another local nickname: Pont y Rhegi (Bridge of Swearing).

I don't get this part, " **A one-way bottleneck along an otherwise two-way main road**", what does the 'otherwise' mean? Does it mean the bridge has 2 roads, one is a one-way bottle neck, the other is a two-way main road?

Need your help! Thanks!!! I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Otherwise" is used as an adverb to show that a subject *is* something in all respects *except* for the detail stated.

For example:

> "She was an otherwise totally black cat with a single white patch".

Your text refers to a road that allows two-way traffic everywhere *except the bridge*, which is evidently so narrow it only allows one line of traffic over at a time. This causes a "bottleneck", which is where multiple lanes of traffic have to either merge or give way to one another because the road *narrows*.

"Along" is used to indicate that something occurs *at some point* either in the passage of time, on a journey, or on some other elongated place you might traverse such as a corridor, or in this case, a road. It means that the bridge occurs at some point on the road.

There are many such bridges on roads in England - [here is one](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@53.8986904,-2.7793241,3a,75y,74h,88.74t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s3-utArbUgpNGloTktg5c5Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) on Google Maps. You will see that there is a white line dividing the road into two-way traffic lanes, but these disappear for the bridge and resume on the other side. There is only room for one car on the bridge at a time and this does cause a bottleneck. It is courteous and generally a wise practice to use your car horn as you approach such a bridge as you can't see what may be approaching on the other side.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't figure out what is meant by 'along' in this sentence, it doesn't seem to mean 'moving in a constant direction on a path or any more or less horizontal surface', which is its meaning in dictionary

Comment: @lola I'll add that in.

Comment: Thank you! It helps a lot!